# Increasing the convergence rate of nested monte carlo

Tags: estimation, monte-carlo

I'm interested in estimating the following expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y] \log \mathbb{E}[X|Y]]$, where only the distribution of $X$ and $Y|x$ is known. To be more specific, let's say both $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors.

$X \in \mathbb{N}^n \sim P(x)$ some discrete distribution. And $Y \in \mathbb{N}^n$, where the elements $Y_i$ are mutually independent when conditioned on $X$. So $Y_i|x = Y_i |x_i \sim Pois(\lambda_i x_i)$

Now, I want to estimate $\mathbb{E}(g(Y))$, where $g(Y) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y] \log \mathbb{E}[X|Y]$. But because I don't have a closed form formula for $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$, the function $g$ itself needs to be estimated from sample. It is straightforward to implement a crude monte carlo estimation of this expectation, but for high dimension, I need a lot of sample in order to get an accurate estimate.

Oddly enough, when I tried to do variance reduction by using control variate $h(Y) = E[X|Y]$, I did not get any improvement in reducing the variance of the estimator. I say this is odd, because this control variate worked really well when I use the analogous, $\mathbb{E}(X)$ to estimate $\mathbb{E}(X \log X)$. So I'm wondering if this is because of the fact that in the original estimation, I actually have to estimate $g$ from data, and somehow this makes control variate ineffective.

In general, I'm wondering if there is any trick or technique specifically for reducing the sample size needed in this type of monte carlo where the function itself needs to be estimated.

---

EDIT: as requested, I've made the question more specific.

EDIT2: as brought up in the comment, I actually noticed that using the control variate made the crude monte carlo estimator less biased, not sure if that's relevant here for reducing variance.

Comment: Cold you make it more precise and less abstract? In this form it may be hard to obtain non-trivial answer.

Comment: (+1) I asked a [similar X Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/250427/7224) a while ago, with no answer (so far).

Comment: Note: [Path sampling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.01382.pdf) is a Monte Carlo technique that returns unbiased estimators of logarithms of integrals.

Comment: sorry about that, I've made some edits. @Xi'an, thank you very much for bringing that up, I actually noticed a bias as well but wasn't sure if that was just sampling error. I'll give that paper a read.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]\log\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ when $X\in\mathbb N^n$?

Comment: yes, sorry @Xi'an if that was confusing notation, you can just think of that as a vector where the i-th element is $\mathbb{E}[X_i|Y] \log \mathbb{E}[X_i|Y]$