# Estimator of $\log \mathbb{E}[X]$

Tags: estimation, monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator

In many fields of statistic we are faced with quantities of type $\log \mathbb{E}[X]$ where $X$ is a generic random variable. However, I never came across any good estimator for this quantity. The only option from the literature is the simple plug-in Monte Carlo (and similar, such as plug-in Importance Sampling). Take some samples $X_i \sim X, \, i=1, \ldots, n$ and plug the MC estimator inside the logarithm 
$$\log \mathbb{E}[X] \approx \log \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) \, .$$ 
The above is clearly biased due to Jensen's inequality, but consistent.

Do you know any **unbiased** estimator of $\log \mathbb{E}[X]$? And a **biased** one with better properties than the plug-in MC?

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/250427/7224) on X validated two years ago. And it got [asked again](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/466803/7224) a few days ago.

Comment: Path sampling provides unbiased estimators of logs of integrals.

Comment: Perhaps the most common instance of this is with the 'log-normal' distribution, for which taking the logs of the data give $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma).$ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) under 'Parameter Estimation' gives relevant answers. But notice that their symbols $\mu$ and $\sigma$ refer to the _normal_ distribution obtained by taking logs. (Natural logs throughout.) // Mean and variance of the _lognormal_ distribution are given at the top of the article.

Comment: Why is the MC estimator biased? Jensen's only applies when sum is compromised of log(X), right?