# Approximating an expectation of a log-product and another expectation

Tags: expected-value, simulation, monte-carlo, conditional-expectation

I am dealing with a variation of a standard problem. Given an objective function $O := E_{a \sim P_\theta(A)} [f(a)]$, we can calculate its gradient $\nabla_\theta O$ as follows:

$$\nabla_\theta O = E_{a \sim P_\theta(A)} [\nabla_\theta \log P_\theta(A=a) f(a)],$$

which can be approximated using samples from $A$.

However, I am facing a more complex situation where the objective function is a conditional expectation: $O^1 := E_{a \sim P_\theta(A)} E_{b \sim P_\phi(B | A = a)} f(a,b)$. I am interested in calculating its gradient $\nabla_{\theta}O^1$.

This leads to the following expression:

$$\nabla_{\theta}O^1 = E_{a \sim P_\theta(A)} [\nabla_\theta \log P_\theta(A = a) E_{b \sim P_\phi(B | A = a)} f(a,b)],$$

If we approximate the inner expectation with samples, it will lead to a biased estimator of the gradient.

My question is about the quality of this estimator and how to best allocate computational resources when approximating it. Given that I can take $N$ samples, where should I expend them? Should I sample the outer term more or the inner term? Assume $N = K + L$,

$$\nabla_{\theta}O^1 \approx \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \nabla_\theta \log P_\theta(A = a^k) \frac{1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^{L} f(a^k,b^l),$$

Alternatively, what if I sample both $a$ and $b$ at the same time? Is there a way to gauge the impact of this?

$$\nabla_{\theta}O^1 \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \nabla_\theta \log P_\theta(A = a^n) f(a^n,b^n).$$

This question [expectation of log of expectation by Monte Carlo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250427/expectation-of-log-of-expectation-by-monte-carlo) considers a problem of a similar form, but its goal is to find an unbiased estimator. I am interested in understanding the trade-offs involved in different sampling strategies and their impact on the quality of the gradient estimator.